# Handling the undefined objects property via lodash

Tags: lodash

`var obj = {
  property1 : {
     subprop : true 
  },
  property2 : {
     subprop : false 
  },
  property4 : {
     subprop : true
  }
}`

Above is the object If I run a code `if(obj.property3.subprop){
                                  // code
                                }`

then the error comes as `cannot read property3 of undefined`

I can handle the above error using javascript, But If I need to handle this through lodash, then is their a function build in lodash for such scenario

Comment: Are you referring to something like `_.isUndefined()` ?

Comment: It doesnt handle the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash's [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) to query a path, with possibly missing parts, without getting an error. You can also use the third param to return a default value.

```js
const obj = {"property1":{"subprop":true},"property2":{"subprop":false},"property4":{"subprop":true}}

if (_.get(obj, 'obj.property3.subprop')) {
  // code
} else {
  console.log('something else')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Another possibility is the new optional chaining, which currently works in all green browsers, but Safari:

```js
const obj = {"property1":{"subprop":true},"property2":{"subprop":false},"property4":{"subprop":true}}

if (obj?.property3?.subprop) {
  // code
} else {
  console.log('something else')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```